# Is a duplicate in two societies, a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, math-se, mathoverflow

Peace be upon you,

Suppose that you have a question which is completely suitable for two societies (e.g. a research-level math question which can be posted to both of math.SE and mathoverflow). Is it considered duplicate if you post in both societies?

If yes, why should you deprive your question to be reviewed by the users of one society? it can be of great benefit to use the opinions of two society users.

If the answer is no, please just tell me and if yes, I suggest that it would be allowed to post such questions but with a duplicate label, beside.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Oh the irony. :P

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely to have a question that is suitable for both our general maths site *and* the research level maths site.

Though, for some sites, some questions may be suitable to both, one of the sites would be *more* suitable (based on the focus of the question) - for instance, programming questions can be asked on both Stack Overflow and on Programmers. However, the first focuses on specific coding issues and the latter on software design.

In general, you shouldn't cross post. If you have a question that can be broken up, you then have 2 questions - each might be suitable to a different site.

Comment: 1- It is not unlikely, because it is allowed (and I think that it is done repeatedly) to ask research level questions in math.SE. 2- It is forbidden or not-recommended? 3- if it is forbidden, how can I announce my suggestion to SE?

Comment: 1. And the other way around? 2. Not recommended. We would rather have one place to find the right answer instead of spread around. 3. You can post a feature-request here, to allow for it. But before you do that, I suggest searching for past discussions and bring something _new_ to the discussion.

Comment: 1- the other way is asking it in mathoverflow 2&3- thanks

Comment: My point was - asking non research level questions on mathoverflow. A research level maths question, though suitable to both sites, should be asked on the research level maths site...